How can I insert relational seed data in Strapi?
Objective
I am looking for a way to seed initial data into Strapi. This is so that business users dont have to insert 1000s of rows when we go live with project. After the initial data, business can then take over and add as needed.
There will be many entities and some entities will have relations with other entities. My plan to to add a bootstrap script which inserts seed data only if a collection is empty, so I don't end up accidentally deleting production data. If a collection is non-empty, associated seed data file will be skipped.
What have I tried?
I created a script which does this in the bootstrap function at startup. The script iterates through data files, and inserts records from files one at a time using their Entity api.
This is working but I am not sure how to do this for entities with relations? Especially bidirectional relations.
For example, if there is a bi-directional, many to many relation between a Restaurant and a Category, which one do I insert? Do I capture IDs while inserting or Strapi has a better way or plugin to insert relational data?
Is this a common requirement? What are others doing to seed initial data into Strapi?
